# File path of image on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, photo

I'm interested in uploading a file (image) from an iPhone library/camera roll to a remote web server.  I already have a script working that will upload any file from the phone to a web server.  However, I assume that to upload an image from the iPhone, I need the PATH to said image.  Is there any way this can be done, once the user picks said image from the camera roll?  I.e., how do I get the file path of an image selected in the camera roll?

I have tried to no avail.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will want to look at the [ALAssetsLibrary](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) functions - these let you access photos and videos that are stored in your Photos and Videos libraries on your iOS device.

Specifically, something like:

```
ALAssetsLibrary *assets = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

[assets enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos
    usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
            //the ALAsset should be one of your photos - stick it in an array and after this runs, use it however you need
        }
    }
    failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        //something went wrong, you can't access the photo gallery
    }
];
```

**EDIT**

If you are using the UIImagePickerController rather than a purely programatical approach, this simplifies it greatly:

In:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *img = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    //you can use UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage for the original image

    //Now, save the image to your apps temp folder, 

    NSString *path = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"upload-image.tmp"];
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
    //you can also use UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img,1); for jpegs
    [imageData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

    //now call your method
    [someClass uploadMyImageToTheWebFromPath:path];
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without that library?  I need to access any given photo X, just the one they click on from the picker.

Comment: For some reason, I thought that you were trying to do do it purely programatically. If you are using a UIImagePickerController, then it becomes very very easy. I'll edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @CrimsonDiego I used your code.But how can I check particular photo and get its path.