# How to get the album source in the Photos app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

When I open the Photos app, there are kinds of albums in it.

Mostly, the right side of the album cell is the album's name and photo count, but if you have photos synchronized from iTunes installed on the Mac or from iCloud, the details under the album name shows not only number but also the source - where this album comes from.

How can I get the source string programatically?

I haven't found any clues in the apple reference documentation.

For example:
-------------------------------------

|   ***_*__*_*_**                                     |                                        
|
|          |       Album Name              |

| |image |                                                         | <------ Table Cell

| |***_*____**|             6 from my Mac       |

                                   |
    -----------------------------------|

What I want is how can I distinguish the photo synchronized through Mac from other camera photos

Comment: possible duplicate of [File path of image on iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11569968/file-path-of-image-on-iphone)

Comment: It's `iCloud` and `iTunes`; attention to detail is essential as programmer.

Comment: Thanks for your help Desdenova,but I'm afraid it's not want I need.Though by that method, I can get the ALAsset,but the ALAsset didn't have property tell where it comes from @Desdenova

Comment: It's pretty optimistic to expect it to be a single property. Read about that thread, that's exactly how you will start. Then you should read ALAssetsLibrary Class Reference - Managing Asset Groups.

Comment: Yes, you are right, in the last a few days i have found the method how to tell the difference in each type of album, but I still can't manage to get some info: 
1.Album can be synchronized by iTunes installed on Mac or Windows, how to get the info where it comes from.
2.Album comes from PhotoStream also indicates the owner how shared it, I want to know the owner info.@Desdenova